# Allow input on an auto-number field in form to create new record in Access

Tags: ms-access, forms, input

I have a form that will display the last record of a table, with a few additional fields from other tables. The PK of the main table is auto-numbering. I need to be able to allow the user to make a change to the auto-numbering field, then determine if the record exists or not, if so - update, if not - insert new. I tried adding an event to the field on field change but whenever I try to click in the field on the form, it just beeps at me. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub JobID_Change()

'Check Bid#, if already exists open selected record for editing
    rstOpenOrder.FindFirst "JobID = " & Me![JobID]
    Do Until rstOpenOrder.NoMatch
    With rstOpenOrder
        'Add new record to end of Recordset object.
        .Edit
        'Edit data.
        !LocationID = Me![LocationID]
        !Description = Me![JobName]
        !BaseBid = Me![BaseBid]
        !GrossMargin = Me![GrossMargin]
        !MDs = Me![ManDays]
        !BidDate = Me![BidDate]
        !ShortDate = Me![ShortDate]
        !EmployeeID = Me![EmployeeID]
        !GC = Me![GCs]
        .Update
        .FindNext "JobID = " & Me![JobID]
        'Save changes.
    End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Auto-numbering is just that, you can not manually added a auto number. You can advance to a new blank record and have the auto-number created which will create the next auto-number. You can list all the existing numbers in a combo box and allow the user to choose a existing number.

Answer (score 2):

It's not generally a good idea to expose autonumber fields in the user interface.  However, if you still want to provide the interface you've described you'll need to do the following:

1. Add an **unbound** text box (I'll call it `IDLookup`)
2. Add an AfterUpdate event to the text box to check for an existing record
3. If the record exists, filter the form to display that one record
4. If not, move the form to a new record (`Me.Recordset.AddNew`)

The key here is that your lookup must be done via an **unbound** text box.  Access won't let you edit anything inside a textbox bound to an AutoNumber field (for good reason!).

Comment: Small expansion: As indicated by JohnDR in his comment to the original Question, Access locks its Auto-number up tighter than a drum (unlike SQL Server, which lets you issue a setting to allow direct insert to its Identity fields (though that's still not a good idea in *most* cases)). This is the good reason to which mwolfe02 refers.

Comment: @RolandTumble: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that SQL Server allows you to alter an identify value? I didn't know that. It is certainly the case that you can append a value to an Autonumber field in Jet/ACE (as well as in SQL Server), because there's not anything all that special about an Autonumber, since it's little more than a long integer field with a default value (and the added property that it can't be changed once populated).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I don't think you can Update an existing Identity value (though I'd have to check to be sure), but if you issue `set identity-insert on` you can insert arbitrary (int) values into a column with the identity property. Of course, the insert is subject to any indexing restrictions, since identity columns are _ususally_ also PKs.

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's the case with Jet/ACE Autonumbers, as well -- that's why I stress that the Jet/ACE Autonumber is a lot more like a long integer field with a special default value than anything else (plus the inability to edit it once populated).

Comment: Oh. I've never even tried to insert to an Ato-number field. Learn something new every day.